# Boolean Expression- Minimization and Law

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I am working on a textbook exercise that asks to "Minimize the following boolean expression using boolean algebraic laws, and then develop a logic circuit for it WITHOUT using a NOT gate".

The expression is 
X= (NOT A) AND (NOT B OR C) OR NOT(C OR A)

First, I attempt to minimize this equation. 
I use distribute law of the left hand side to turn (NOT A) AND (NOT B OR C) to (NOT A AND NOT B) OR (NOT A AND C).

So following this law, the new equation is 
(NOT A AND NOT B) OR (NOT A AND C) OR (NOT C AND NOT A).

Grouping at the right hand side of ((NOT A AND C) OR (NOT C AND NOT A)), shows that there is another law that states (AB + A(NOT B) = A).

I use this LAW (Call this law ?) here to simplify the entire expression to simply NOT(A).

So the new equation is (NOT A AND NOT B) OR (NOT A).

I use the redundancy law, which states that (A + AB = A), to change the entire expression to simply NOT(A).

Following this minimization, I have successfully minimized the entire equation to X=NOT(A). Truth tables show they are functionally equivalent.

My two questions are
1. The area where I saw ? Law, I have searched for a name for this law but have not been able to find one. Is there a name for the law (AB + A(NOT B) = A)?
2. If the function is NOT(A), I am not sure how one could design a logic circuit without using a NOT gate? I was thinking that maybe a NAND gate could work, but those have inverters. If it asks to not use a NOT gate, is it still valid to use a NAND gate?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no name for `AB + A(NOT B) = A`, the equation is just a consequence of the *distribution law* `AB + A(NOT B) = A(B + NOT B)` and the fact that `B + NOT B = TRUE`.

Regarding your concern about `NAND`, yes you need to used it because there is no way to get `NOT` from just `OR` and `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply answer

```
X= NOT(A*A) = NAND(A,A)
```

or

```
X=NOT(A+A) = NOR(A,A)
```

An inverter uses either a resistor and a transistor or a ptype and an ntype transistor in series. Nand and nor gates add at least one or two transistors to the equation. It isn't a practical question to ask someone not to use a NOT gate.